# Additional constructor for templated type for <char> only

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class with one template parameter 'T'. I want the class to have a constructor, but if T is char only to have an additional constructor "const char*" as a parameter.

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    // Construct a container from an array of T's
    Container(const T* data, int count);

    // For char only construct a container from a nul terminated string
    // I *only* want this constructor to be valid when T is char
    Container(const T* data);
};
```

Is there any way to achieve this, so that I can do :-

```
const char* init = "Hello";
Container<char> data = init;
```

Will compile but

```
const int init[] = {1, 3, 4};
Container<int> data = init;
```

Will not compile.

Comment: use SFINAE. Do you have a c++11 compiler? look for is_enabled.

Comment: See also [*How to use sfinae for selecting constructors?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603163/how-to-use-sfinae-for-selecting-constructors)

Comment: @Gombat do you mean [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: yes :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could wrap it in a constructor template and use SFINAE:

```
template <typename U=T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, char>::value>>
Container(const U* )
{
    ...
}
```

That way, for `Container<char>`, this constructor is viable, but for `Container<int>` it will be ill-formed and removed from the overload set.

A lesser alternative would simply be:

```
Container(const char* ) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, char>::value, "!");
}
```

This would still give you the `const char*` constructor when you need it, and no `const T*` constructor for other `T`s. But then we'd still have `std::is_constructible<Container<int>, const char*>` - which could break other logic. So stick with SFINAE.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that his template constructor has two parameters, and he wants one parameter for the case of a char template. Can't do it like this. This requires template specialization.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's... not true. The constructor does use one argument. The fact that it has two template parameters is irrelevant. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7da5bbd564dec5c)

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [Static Assertion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void Foo(T) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, const char*>::value, "T must be const char *");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* c = "c";
    Foo(c); // compile
    Foo(1); // don't compile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the constructor for char:

```
template <> Container<char>::Container(const char* data) {}
```

Here is the example:

[ideone](http://ideone.com/y1RAIp)

Comment: AFAIK, you can't change the signature in a specialization

Comment: Question: "Is there any way A) Compile (and work of course) B) not compile." Answer: See the example.  But downvoting people do not even bother to look at that.

Comment: Your solution is to provide definition only for `char` version and got a linker error for non-`char` cases.

Comment: Linker error isn't the best way to signal invalid type template argument

Comment: It *does* compile, it just doesn't link.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki he hasn't changed the signature, he has specialized it for `Container(const T* data)` where `T = char`.

Comment: I did not just compile and posted anyway. I have tried on my environment (gcc 4.9.2 debian). Compiled&linked&run.

Comment: @MertMertce Only because your ideone link has the offending constructor call commented out. If you [try to use it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82978eeb556b16f2), it will compile but not link.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode 1. the demo was added after my comment, 2. providing a definition only as a specialization makes little sense anyway

Answer (score -1):

This is called template specialization:

```
template<>
class Container<char>
{
public:
    Container(const char *);

    // ... the rest of the class declaration
};
```

Now, what this actually does, for all intents and purposes, is create a separate class. You will have to write and declare all of its other methods, in addition to the constructor. This would likely call for quite a bit of code duplication, with your main template class, but it's usually possible to organize things a bit, with a help of a common inheritance and/or a base class.

With all of that in place:

```
Container<int>
```

will resolve to your main template, and

```
Container<char>
```

gets you your specialized class. Specialization is, essentially, choosing one of several alternative templates based on template parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no alternative to template specialization, when a constructor's, or a method's signature must be different for a particular template parameter.

Comment: Actually there are quite a few alternatives, all involving template metaprogramming. As long as you have a good metaprogramming library at hand to remove the boiler-plate code, it's even painless.

Comment: An easy alternative is SFINAE. I have used it to good effect in real code.

Comment: @Gombat: You can still create a (private) base class which hold only the specialization.

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, in some cases this is also a good solution, e.g. there is no template default parameter for functions before c++11.