# Conditionally enable constructor in C++ class

Tags: c++, constructor, enable-if

I am learning how to use `std::enable_if` and I have had some degree of success so far at conditionally enabling and disabling methods in my classes. I template the methods against a boolean, and the return type of such methods is an `std::enable_if` of such boolean. Minimal working example here:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct input {};
struct output {};

template <class io> struct is_input { static constexpr bool value = false; };

template <> struct is_input<input> { static constexpr bool value = true; };

template <class float_t, class io, size_t n> class Base {
private:
  std::array<float_t, n> x_{};

public:
  Base() = default;
  Base(std::array<float_t, n> x) : x_(std::move(x)) {}
  template <class... T> Base(T... list) : x_{static_cast<float_t>(list)...} {}

  // Disable the getter if it is an input class
  template <bool b = !is_input<io>::value>
  typename std::enable_if<b>::type get(std::array<float_t, n> &x) {
    x = x_;
    }

  // Disable the setter if it is an output class
  template <bool b = is_input<io>::value>
  typename std::enable_if<b>::type set(const std::array<float_t, n> &x) {
    x_ = x;
    }
};

int main() {
  Base<double, input, 5> A{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  Base<double, output, 3> B{3, 9, 27};

  std::array<double, 5> a{5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  std::array<double, 3> b{1, 1, 1};

  // A.get(a);   Getter disabled for input class
  A.set(a);

  B.get(b);
  // B.set(b);   Setter disabled for input class

  return 0;
}
```

However, I cannot apply this procedure to conditionally enable **constructors**, since they have no return type. I have tried templating against the value of `std::enable_if` but the class fails to compile:

```
template <class io> class Base{
private:
  float_t x_;
public:
  template <class x = typename std::enable_if<std::is_equal<io,input>::value>::type> Base() : x_{5.55} {}
}
```

The compiler error looks like:

```
In instantiation of ‘struct Base<output>’ -- no type named ‘type’ in  ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
```

As explained [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function), when a class temnplate is instantiated, it instantiates all its member declarations (though not necessarily their definitions). The declaration of that constructor is ill-formed and hence the class cannot be instantiated.

How would you circumvent this issue? I Appreciate any help :)

**EDIT:**

I would like to have something like the following:

```
struct positive{};
struct negative{};

template <class float_t, class io> class Base{
private:
  float_t x_;
public:
  template <class T = io, typename = typename std::enable_if<
                          std::is_same<T, positive>::value>::type>
  Base(x) : x_(x) {}

  template <class T = io, typename = typename std::enable_if<
                          std::is_same<T, negative>::value>::type>
  Base(x) : x_(-x) {}
```

If that is possible at all.

Comment: Can the down-voter please explain the reason of his downvote?

Comment: Probably because a simple search finds a duplicate.

Comment: So why just don't close as duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways for constructors as you cannot use it in return type

Default template parameter:

```
template <class io> class Base
{
private:
    float_t x_;
public:
    template <class T = io,
              typename std::enable_if<std::is_equal<T, input>::value, int>::type = 0>
    Base() : x_{5.55} {}
};
```

Default argument:

```
template <class io> class Base{
private:
    float_t x_;
public:
    template <class T = io>
    Base(typename std::enable_if<std::is_equal<T, input>::value, int>::type = 0) :
        x_{5.55}
    {}
};
```

You cannot use SFINAE in your case as parameter depend only of your class parameter and not of template parameter of your function.

For:

```
template <class T = io, typename = typename std::enable_if<
                      std::is_same<T, positive>::value>::type>
Base(x) : x_(x) {}

template <class T = io, typename = typename std::enable_if<
                      std::is_same<T, negative>::value>::type>
Base(x) : x_(-x) {}
```

You do a common mistake: default template argument are not part of the signature, so you only declare and define twice

```
template <class, typename>
Base::Base(x);
```

That's why I used

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, input>::value, int>::type = 0
```

where type is on left of `=`, so you will have 2 different type, so 2 different signatures.

C++20 adds `requires` which allow to discard method simply:

```cpp
template <class float_t, class io> class Base{
private:
  float_t x_;
public:

  Base(x) requires(std::is_same<io, positive>::value) : x_(x) {}
  Base(x) requires(std::is_same<io, negative>::value) : x_(-x) {}

  // ...
};
```

Comment: I understand the problem that you point out. If the constructor was not templated against a class parameter, but against it own parameter, we could use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603163/how-to-use-sfinae-for-selecting-constructors. But this is not the case here. Is there any way around? I have edited my question to make it more clear. Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: Edited to pinpoint your other problem in your edit.

Comment: That is some very valuable insight (for me) regarding default arguments and signature! But with the solution having `int`, the method is not disabled for `std::enable_if<false,int>::type`. It stills compiles perfectly fine. I am thinking now that maybe `std::conditional` is what I am lloking for, right?

Comment: `std::enable_if<false,int>::type` is an hard error, `std::enable_if<cond<T>::value,int>::type` with `cond<T>::value` resulting to false would disallow the overload. `std::conditional` doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: You are completly right! I was compiling a slightly different file than the one I posted here, where a different constructor was being called. And yeah, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Did you perhaps meant to write `std::is_same` because there is no `std::is_equal`.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for. Would you mind elaborating why you used `T = io` instead of using `io` directly?

Comment: SFINAE applies on template function and should be dependent on that template, if you use `io` directly, error comes from the class template parameter. C++20 adds a simple fix with `Base() requires(std::is_equal<io, input>::value) :
        x_{5.55}
    {}`.